# Software to take screenshots during gameplay?

Tags: android, screenshot

I have a Kindle Fire 1st Generation, and there is no way to take screenshots using the Power and Volume buttons, like there is in newer version of the Kindle Fire.

I need a good app that lets me take screenshots while I am using other apps, browsing the web, etc.

I would prefer something that is lightweight and does not have a large list of unneeded permissions. I also need something that doesn't require root access, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

For a root required fix to this problem, you can download [screenshot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geeksoft.screenshot&hl=en). This app is free.

Screenshot allows you to shake your device to take a picture of your screen without having to touch any buttons. Just simply set it up, enable it, and take screenshots to your heart's content!

[image: screenshot of the settings] [image: screenshot of enable detection]
<sup>Screenshots of settings (left) and enable detection (right; click images for full-sized variants)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

**[Drocap2](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.gmail.drocap2.drocap2)** is what I've used for quite a time, until the "native screenshot method" was introduced to Android. Though it hasn't been updated for quite a time, it always did a good job. Pre-condition is a rooted device.

**Drocap2** gives you the choice of multiple triggers, including a timer trigger (countdown to X before "shooting") and a shake-trigger (does a screenshot when you shake the device). These actions can be activated via the notification area, where the service "sits".

[image: Shake Trigger activation] [image: Options]
<sup>Activating the *Shake Trigger* (left), preferences (right; click images for full-sized variants)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

For a non-root fix to this problem, you can download [No Root Screenshot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.edwardkim.android.screenshotitfullnoroot&hl=en). This is a paid app. There is also a trial version available [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.edwardkim.android.screenshotitfree&hl=en)

This app has some restrictions. You have to connect to a computer to set it up and you have to do so everytime you restart your phone. You shake the device to take a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of setup instuctions] 
[image: Screenshot of windows setup]
<sup>Screenshots of setup instructions (left) and windows setup (right; click for full-sized variants)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Android Screencast](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/).

It works without root, but requires you to connect to a computer via USB.

It is Open Source.

Your phone's screen is shown on the computer's screen, so you can take screenshots with your OS' normal screenshot method (I agree a more direct feature would be better).

[image: Screenshot]